# How to delete XML nodes containing specific value using Java

Tags: java, xml

I want to delete all nodes containing the value `#delete`, for example in the below XML, `<id>` and `<price>` nodes should be deleted as their values contain `#delete`

```
<root>
  <product>
       <id>#delete</id>
       <name>shirt</name>
       <desc>product description</desc>
       <price>#delete</price>
  </product>
</root>
```

Comment: you can use XSLT

Comment: Or parse it to a Document, then modify the nodes. What did you try?

Comment: requirement is to code it in Java

Comment: Use DOM to modify your XML

Answer (score 0):

If your XML example is in a file named `products.xml` in your working directory, then this snippet should work and print the result to console.

This is meant as an example to give you an idea how `org.w3c.dom` could be used for this (if your XML structure is deeper as in your example then you have to recursively read all children)

```
//load DOM    
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = builder.parse(new File("products.xml"));
//get all products
NodeList products = dom.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (int i = 0; i < products.getLength(); i++) {
    Node product = products.item(i);
    NodeList nodes = product.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < nodes.getLength(); j++) {
        Node node = nodes.item(j);
        // check content
        if ("#delete".equals(node.getTextContent())) {
            product.removeChild(node);
        }
    }
}
//write to system out
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(Method.XML, encoding, true);
XMLSerializer xml = new XMLSerializer(writer, format);
xml.serialize(dom);
```